# Private web.config for each developer

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, web-config

Consider a group of developers working on an ASP.net web application. Each developer would like to have a private version of the web.config.

By "private" I mean that a developer can freely change the file to suit their dev/test needs at any given moment, without it affecting other team members and without ending up in source control.

How can one go about achieving this with Visual Studio 2015?

My closest solution so far is to have a "private" [Solution Configuration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166577.aspx) with a matching [Web.config Transformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(VS.100).aspx) file ("web.private.config") that's excluded from source control.

But this is not a satisfactory solution because:

a. The transformation is not run automatically when debugging (with F5). The developers need to remember to run it manually.

b. The result of the transformation ends up in the main "web.config" file which is, naturally, included in source control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have web.config include an external file (via `configSource`) and add that file to `.gitignore`

Comment: This is likely going to solve my problem. What happens if the external file is not present on disk? Any errors thrown or is it just ignored?

Comment: cant recall ottomh but https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.configsource(v=vs.110).aspx claim Gets or sets the name of the include file in which the associated configuration section is defined, **if such a file exists.**

Answer (score 7):

We had a very similar problem but only needed personalized versions of the <appSettings> section in *Web.config*.

In this situation the inclusion of an external file through `configSource` turned out to be problematic, as this attribute completely **replaces** the <appSettings>-node. So there remains no way to keep global key/values AND personal key/values for all developers. The whole section is completely replaced by the included private file.

What we need is **both** global and private <appSettings>. The solution we found was the `file` attribute. It allows to **merge** Web.config settings with settings from an additional file.

We ended up with a construct like this one:

```
<!-- Web.config with global appSettings) -->
...
<appSettings file="Web.PERSONAL.config">
    <add key="BaseUrl" value="https://projectname.dev.local" />
    ...
</appSettings>
...
```

­

```
<!-- Web.PERSONAL.config with personal appSettings -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appSettings >
  <add key="EmailSmtpUser" value="my.name@my.domain.com" />
  <add key="EmailSmtpPwd" value="***" />
</appSettings >
```

If you put identical keys in both files, the *Web.PERSONAL.config* version will overwrite the *Web.config* version.

The file *Web.PERSONAL.config* must be excluded from Git through .gitignore .

**Keep in mind:**
While `configSource` works for ALL nodes in Web.config, the `file` attribute is restricted to <appSettings>.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is to host your local development site in a separate location from your Visual Studio solution. You can then use [publish profiles](https://webtooling.visualstudio.com/project-system/publishing/#file-system,-ftp-or-web-deploy) to publish changes to that location and [web.config transforms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx) to maintain a separate local config for each developer. Each developer would use a different publish profile which transforms the web.config with their own transform and deploys the transformed web.config to the publish location. You can then attach a debugger to the published site using Visual Studio's Debug > Attach To Process option.

Comment: Thanks. This is a viable approach but having to re-deploy and use remote debugging multiple times a day is not convenient enough for this team. The main process to be debugged needs to run on the developer's own machine.

Comment: I'm not talking about remote debugging. Create an iis site locally, publish from your cloned repo into it, then attach a local debugger. The "separate location" I mentioned is not a separate server, just elsewhere on your local file system. Even better if your local devs use the same location and same named local db they can probably share same publish profile.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a lot of value in standardising dev environments so that one can just download the solution and run it.

Custom, long term/permanent, developer specific configs will sooner or later lead to a subtle bug that will be tricky to find.

My solution to your problem would be to find out the reason(s) why permanent individual configs are needed and have a look if these environment specific differences can be eliminated.

Comment: I very much agree that standardising dev environments is generally the way to move forward. In this case there is resistance from the team as the system is made up of multiple standalone web services and team members would rather not have to launch all of them on their machines when debugging.

Comment: @Urig If the team doesn't want to launch all services because it's difficult then it can be made easier (launch_all.bat?).